# Java Applet is unable to access an external jar file that reads a C# DLL

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, dll, applet

I have created a java wrapper to read a POS DLL file using jni4net. I am able to execute the application through eclipse. When I try to access the DLL functions through the applet I am getting an error. The applet is unable to read the jini4net.jar file functions.
I have defined the jar file in the applet archive attribute.

Can you please help me resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: This is the Applet:applet code="com.test.DLLApplet.class"  width="300" height="300" 
 name="tApplet" 
`   id="tApplet" 
 archive="jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar, 
    DLLApplet.jar,
    MessageApp.j4n.jar"
 /applet

Comment: When loading ddl files from a applet, the whole applet needs to be signed

Comment: This is the exception I am getting:
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
net/sf/jni4net/Bridge
        at com.test.DLLApplet$1.run(DLLApplet.java:105)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.test.DLLApplet.autorizeTransaction(DLLApplet.java:97)
        at com.test.DLLApplet.main(DLLApplet.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge

Comment: The HTML code to launch the applet, as well as the stack trace, should be part of the question. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35431800/edit) the question to include it.